# how to let intellij know the file format of xml with other file extension names?

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea

I don't know for what reason(maybe for safety?),the legacy project's spring configuration xmls what named to applicationContext.XCVASF.static but not applicationContext.xml.It's not possible to rename them.How to configure intellij idea to let it know their's format is xml? It's better to let it know it's spring's configuration files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Settings -> File Types then from the first select list find and select XML option then from the bottom box click add your custom type.[image]

Answer (score 0):

go to settings, file types and add your extensions to the XML files to have intellij recognize it as xml